# Where does NotePad++ think it is saving to?

Tags: notepad++, editing

1. I can drag & drop a file into Windows' NotePad and see its contents.
2. I can then drag & drop the same file into NotePad++ and see completely different contents.

Initially, no data - but I can enter characters and save the file.  ANd I'm not talking undisplayable v. binary or anything; I'm saying completely different text.  Timestamp on disc remains unchanged - but I can repeat the steps above with the same results !!  What gives ?
(have occasionally noticed similar quirks in Edit+)

If I edit the file in NotePad and save, it looks changed - when reloaded into NotePad.
If I edit the spurious file (same filename) in NotePad++, and save, it too, keeps those changes when reloaded in NotePad++.....

But there seem to be 2 copies of the file somewhere.  Is the data cached somewhere instead of using IO ??  Coz that's not nice. Save should mean "save". no ?

~AS.

Comment: Check out the open files by using http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx - you'll want to set up the filtering to cut down on the excess stuff not related to notepad++.exe or whatever, but that should get you an answer.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on XP with Portable NotePad++. Both programs receive the same pasted text and both save the same file. Some questions/tests suggest themselves:- 1. Are you using any sort of clip-board manager? 2. Are you sure both programs are saving to the same directory? (In both programs, in **Save As** pull down the _Save in:_ directory path to check.) 3. If you create a new file from one program, check that you can see it from the other before saving. 4. Is there any possibility that the two programs were launched from different accounts?

Comment: okay, user is the same for both apps (NotePad & Npp).
Interestingly (or not), if I save the file with a new name - same directory (Save As...) it does _not_ appear in my directory.
If I Copy the file in the directory and Drag&Drop the new one into NotePad++ it appears as it should.  If I delete the old file and rename the new one the old name... voila!  Drag&Drop one again gives my spurious data...
My belief is that NPP has corrupted the directory somehow, and is writing data somewhere else.. OR the LHC did create a black hole afterall; but not in Switzerland - other side of the earth, in NZ.

Comment: I have never seen what you describe.  Something weird must being going on unique to your system.

Comment: @Zoredache, Well I'm sure you're right.  The only thing misbehaving is **NotePad++**
I think it has something to do with Windows mapping pseudo directories to real ones - and NPP perhaps not resolving them correctly.
I can reproduce this issue will by creating a file in the directory, editing it in NotePad, saving, then opening in NPP.
I've also noticed quite a few files (when I choose Open...) which I have previously deleted or moved !!